# Xcode gives “spotlight quit unexpectedly” error message - Spotlight [1328]

Tags: xcode, macos

Process:               Spotlight [1328]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Applications/Spotlight.app/Spotlight
Identifier:            Spotlight
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [1176]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [744]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-10-06 12:25:04.560 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H2)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D09DDD7C-09E5-84F9-6FF9-4F336C126DD8

Time Awake Since Boot: 3100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/natallysonsaraiva/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/19H2/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0.18A372
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libutil.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x000000010f4cb14a __mmap + 10
1   dyld                            0x000000010f4c977a mmap + 81
2   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eb64ff ImageLoaderMachO::mapSegments(int, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 505
3   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eb7475 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, unsigned int, unsigned int, linkedit_data_command const*, encryption_info_command const*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 341
4   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eb2ced ImageLoaderMachO::instantiateFromFile(char const*, int, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, stat const&, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 143
5   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea36be dyld::loadPhase6(int, stat const&, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&) + 793
6   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea8653 dyld::loadPhase5(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 1693
7   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea7f54 dyld::loadPhase4(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 185
8   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea7ccf dyld::loadPhase3(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 1434
9   dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea7446 dyld::loadPhase1(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 186
10  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea3358 dyld::loadPhase0(char const*, char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&, std::__1::vector<char const*, std::__1::allocator<char const*> >*) + 186
11  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea3036 dyld::load(char const*, dyld::LoadContext const&, unsigned int&) + 185
12  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea8b88 dyld::libraryLocator(char const*, bool, char const*, ImageLoader::RPathChain const*, unsigned int&) + 55
13  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf14c ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 346
14  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
15  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
16  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
17  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
18  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
19  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
20  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eaf424 ImageLoader::recursiveLoadLibraries(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 1074
21  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102eae158 ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, char const*) + 90
22  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea5671 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&, unsigned int) + 383
23  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea6adc dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 3803
24  dyld_sim                        0x0000000102ea11c7 start_sim + 122
25  dyld                            0x000000010f47d85c dyld::useSimulatorDyld(int, macho_header const*, char const*, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*, unsigned long*) + 2308
26  dyld                            0x000000010f47b4f4 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 837
27  dyld                            0x000000010f476227 dyldbootstrap::start(dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, int, char const**, dyld3::MachOLoaded const*, unsigned long*) + 453
28  dyld                            0x000000010f476025 _dyld_start + 37

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x000000011e26b000  rbx: 0x0000000102f2afe0  rcx: 0x00007ffeecd66328  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
rdi: 0x000000011e26b000  rsi: 0x0000000000004000  rbp: 0x00007ffeecd66350  rsp: 0x00007ffeecd66328
r8: 0x0000000000000003   r9: 0x0000000000001000  r10: 0x0000000000000012  r11: 0x0000000000000202
r12: 0x0000000000000003  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000004000  r15: 0x0000000000000012
rip: 0x000000010f4cb14a  rfl: 0x0000000000000202  cr2: 0x00007ffee4874c2c

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x020000c5
Trap Number:     133

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=795.2M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=795.2M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=9620K written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=9620K(100%)

```
                            VIRTUAL   REGION
```

REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
===========                     =======  =======
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1
Stack                             8192K        2
__DATA                            10.9M      356
__DATA_CONST                      24.5M      275
__DATA_DIRTY                        16K        3
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1
__LINKEDIT                       540.9M      296
__TEXT                           254.3M      286
__UNICODE                          588K        1
dylib (reserved)                    36K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
mapped file                         16K        1
shared memory                        8K        2
===========                     =======  =======
TOTAL                            895.3M     1225
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   895.3M     1225

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM 195.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Dual-Core Intel Core i5, 1,8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics6000Item, Intel HD Graphics 6000, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445364533303445452D45474345000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1615.2)
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.6f7, 3 services, 25 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121,33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: HyperX Alloy FPS Pro Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2

Comment: I'm getting this too and it's highly annoying.